# Arch Linux latest version that included AIF

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I used to install Arch Linux via graphical installer, but it was removed in one of the releases, because "this is not the priority and no one wants to maintain it". I cant find out which release is latest that included graphical installer? Or is there any way to install latest release through graphical installer? It was very convenient for me to use graphical installer, because i can easily choose which desktop environment i want to use, which packages i want to be pre-installed, etc.

P.S.: Which linux distributions use Deepin as native desktop environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It was removed in release 2012.07.15.](https://www.archlinux.org/news/install-media-20120715-released/) and it looks like [2011.08.19. was the last one that had it](https://www.archlinux.org/news/20110819-installation-media/) as the notes even mention it getting new features.
If you find the cli-based installation process daunting, you can use an [Arch-derivative](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch-based_distributions#Active) with a graphical installer, like Antergos or Manjaro. [Manjaro has a Deepin edition](https://manjaro.org/download/deepin/), but you can easily install it on any other distro by installing the `deepin` package group.

Comment: Thank you very much, for you suggestion about using Arch-derivatives. I`m already using Manjaro Deepin. It looks so great, and the main pro about it that is has AUR.